# Pass array as separate arguments

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to pass several elements in a String array as separate arguments to a method, and I can't find a solution to the nearly universal `method(*args)`, better depicted by something like this in python (I know, awful usage):

```
def foo(*args):
    print sorted(args)

arr=[0,5,2,7,3]
foo(*arr)
```

Comment: since you can't predict (when writing the method) how many elements the array will have, how would you do this? there is always the
method(String... params) approach

Comment: @Hackerdarshi "better depicted by something like this in **python**"

Comment: @inori your question is vague, what do you expect? is what I pointed at in my first reply what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think `method(*args)` is universal. If it were, then it would exist in Java as written

Comment: @cricket_007 "**nearly** universal"

Comment: I don't think that syntax exists in C or its variants either. I have only seen *args in python for an unpacked list

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Varargs is what you are looking for.

With var args you can do

```
static void receiveInputs(String... values){  
  // To do with values array
 }
```

And you can pass unpredicted no of args

```
receiveInputs("in1","in2");
```

and works also for

```
receiveInputs("in1","in2", "in3","in4");
```

and works also for

```
String[] s = new String[]{"in1","in2", "in3","in4"};

receiveInputs(s);
```

Comment: Varargs is almost the opposite of what I was looking for, but it's relevant and on the right track. +1 (isn't it common knowledge to anyone who took a basic compsci course?)

Comment: @Inori How could we know whether you've taken any Comp Sci courses?